# How to use the value of an Ansible variable to target and get the value of a hostvar?

Tags: variables, reference, ansible

I'm in a situation where I have multiple Ansible roles, using multiple group_vars. Spread around each host's vars (depending on the host) is a number of directory paths, each in different places within the hostvar tree.

I need to ensure that a certain number of these directories exist when provisioning. So I created a role that uses the `file` module to ensure that these directories exist. Well, it would do, if I could figure out how to get it to work.

I have a group_var something similar to:

```
ensure_dirs:
  - "daemons.builder.dirs.pending"
  - "processor.prep.logdir"
  - "shed.logdir"
```

Each of these 3 values maps directly to a group var that contains a string value that represents the corresponding filesystem path for that var, for example:

```
daemons:
  builder:
    dirs:
      pending: /home/builder/pending
```

I would like to somehow iterate over `ensure_dirs` and evaluate each item's value in order to resolve it to the FS path.

I've tried several approaches, but I can't seem to get the value I need. The following is the most success I've had, which simply returns the literal of the constructed string.

```
- file:
    dest: "hostvars['{{ ansible_hostname }}']['{{ item.split('.') | join(\"']['\") }}']"
    state: directory
  with_items: "{{ ensure_dirs }}"
```

This results in directories named, for example, `hostvars['builder']['daemons']['builder']['dirs']['pending']` in the working directory. Of course, what I want the file module to work with the the *value* stored at that path in the hostvars, so that it will instead ensure that `/home/builder/pending` exists.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple way – template your group variable.

**group_var**

```
ensure_dirs:
  - "{{ daemons.builder.dirs.pending }}"
  - "{{ processor.prep.logdir }}"
  - "{{ shed.logdir }}"
```

**task**

```
- file:
    path: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
  with_items: "{{ ensure_dirs }}"
```

Comment: Of course. How did I not think of that. I guess I couldn't see the wood for the trees! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create and use a lookup plugin.

Ansible defines lots of [lookup plugins](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup), the most popular is 'items' when you use 'with_items'. Convention is 'with_(plugin name)'.

To create you lookup plugin:

- Edit file [ansible.cfg](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/examples/ansible.cfg) and uncomment key 'lookup_plugins' with value './plugins/lookup'
- Create a plugin file named 'dirs.py' in './plugins/lookup'
- Use it in your playbook:

`- file:
    dest: "{{ item }}"
    state: directory
  with_dirs: "{{ ensure_dirs }}"`

- implement you plugin dirs.py with something like that (see [lookup plugins](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup) for more examples)

`class LookupModule(LookupBase):
    def run(self, terms, **kwargs):
        return [dir.replace('.', '/') for dir in terms]`

Advantages:
* Your playbook is more easy to read
* You can create python unitary tests for you plugin and improve it

Comment: Hmm... OP needs to evaluate variables inside `ensure_dirs`.